# Regex takes only last match

Tags: java, regex

I wrote a regex for if/elif/else statement
 `(\s|^)if\s*\((.*?)\)\s*then\s+do\s+(.*?)\s+end\n+(elif\s*\((.*?)\)\s*then\s+do\s+(.*?)\s+end\n+)*(else\s+then\s+do\s+(.*?)\s+end\n+)?` but when there are 2 or more elif statements it just take the last condition and statement

```
if (condition1) then do 
    Statement1
end
elif (condition2) then do
    Statement2
end
elif (condition3) then do 
    Statement3
end
else then do
    ElseStatement
end
```

The output:

```
Group 1.    0-0 
Group 2.    4-14    condition1
Group 3.    26-33   aagahd;
Group 4.    77-120  elif (condition3) then do Statement3 end
Group 5.    83-93   condition3
Group 6.    105-115 Statement3
Group 7.    120-144 else then do ElseStatement end
Group 8.    133-139 ElseStatement
```

I don't know why, but it doesn't define the first elif statement. What's wrong?

P.S. I'm using java

Comment: Read this java documentation like @Don

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/   @Don

Answer (score -1):

The asterisk needs to go into the group, not outside. If it is outside, only the last match for the group is stored in that group.

Read this [blog post](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html) for a more in-depth explanation that I think applies here.

Comment: I've added one more brackets after * and ? and nothing changed

Comment: `(\s|^)if\s*\((.*?)\)\s*then\s+do\s+(.*?)\s+end\n+((elif\s*\((.*?)\)\s*then\s+do\s+(.*?)\s+end\n+)*)((else\s+then\s+do\s+(.*?)\s+end\n+)?)`